# Why are `font-url` and `image-url` not respecting `config.assets.prefix`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline, compass-sass, sprockets

I am trying to set an app's `config.assets.prefix`, to `/api/assets`. Stylesheet & javascript links work fine, as well as rails image helpers.

However the `font-url` and `image-url` sass helpers are still using `/assets` instead of `/api/assets`.

The fonts & images are available at both paths, but I need the path to be `/api/assets` because the app is one of several living behind a Cloudfront distribution, and the behaviour uses the `api` path prefix to direct requests to the correct origin.

Why are `font-url` and `image-url` not respecting `config.assets.prefix`?

(app is still on Rails 4.2.x)

Comment: I just checked, and the **Rails** helper `font_url` behaves correctly. It is just the **sass** helpers `font-url` and `image-url` that are misbehaving.

Comment: hmm, I tried adding .erb to my .scss file and using `<% font_url %>`, but that also returns `/assets/...` instead of `/api/assets/...`

Comment: I believe `font-url` and `image-url` are `compass` helpers not sass helpers. So are you using compass in your rails app?

Comment: yes, I am using compass

Comment: Have you tried creating a `compass/config.rb` file and setting the value of `fonts_dir` and `images_dir` to the value of `config.assets.prefix`?